# Man pages are outdated

Tags: macos, bash, man

Background:

I recently learned about the mv -t flag option in bash, but when I checked the man pages on my computer, there was no mention of it. The man pages were dated 9 July 2002. I ssh-ed into another UNIX system and found the mv -t option in the man pages there, dated December 2015.

Problem:

I reckoned my bash shell needed upgrading, so I upgraded from version 3.2.57(1) to 4.3.42(1), following the steps here: http://clubmate.fi/upgrade-to-bash-4-in-mac-os-x/

Now when I run "echo $BASH_VERSION" it says "4.3.42(1)-release", but if I do "bash --version" it returns "version 3.2.57(1)-release".
The man pages are still from 2002.

Any ideas what could be going on?

Comment: OSX is a variant of BSD. You have to be more specific when you say "UNIX". The OSX man pages are also available online: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/ -- the `mv` command on the Mac does not appear to have a `-t` option. `-t` may be a GNU-specific option

Comment: Note that, with homebrew, the bash you're using may not be the first bash in your $PATH. What does `type -a bash` tell you?

Comment: After typing 'type -a bash' I get the following:

bash is /bin/bash
bash is /usr/local/bin/bash

Comment: The other UNIX system is Linux. I use a Mac OSX.
Is there any way of forcing Mac to use the GNU shell?

Comment: /usr/local/bin/bash will be the homebrew bash. For GNU utils, homebrew is probably your best option

Comment: What shell you're running should have nothing to do with what version of `mv` you're running. You seem to be confused and thinking `/bin/mv` is a shell builtin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Glenn Jackman for helpful comments above.

The problem was due to a difference between GNU Command Line tools and OSX Command Line Tools.
To solve the problem, I followed the steps at this website:
https://www.topbug.net/blog/2013/04/14/install-and-use-gnu-command-line-tools-in-mac-os-x/

Now I am running bash version 4.3.42(1) and the man pages are working as I had hoped.